# Finding solution of recurrence relations $T(n) = 2T(n/3)+n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution

Evaluate:

**$$T(n)=2T(n/3)+n$$**

**$$T(n/3)=2T(n/9)+n/3$$**

**$$T(n/9)=2T(n/27)+n/9$$**

Substitute the following result:

**$$T(n)=2(2(2T(n/27)+n/9)+n/3)+n$$**

**$$T(k)=2^k T(n/3^k)+n/3^{k-1}+n/3^{k-2}+....+n/3^0$$**

**$$T(k)=2^k T(n/3^k)+\frac{(1-1/3^k)}{(1-1/3)}n$$**

Generalization:    $$T(n/3^k=1)=1\text{, (Since T(1) = 1)}$$ 
                   $$T(n=3^k)=1$$ 
                   $$T(k=\log_3 n)=1$$
Thus:    $$T(n)=2^{\log_3 n}T(n/3^{\log_3 n})+\frac{(1-1/3^{\log_3 n})}{(1-1/3)}n$$

$$T(n)=2^{\log_3 n}+3/2(n-1)$$

But when I tested the N input to the solution above, the result does not match with T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n. For example I input 27 to the following solution:

(NOTE: **$T(3)=2T(1)+3=5$**
**$T(9)=2T(3)+9=19$**
**$T(27)=2T(9)+27=65$**)
$$T(27)=2^{\log_3 27}+3/2(27-1)=47$$

So I conclude that I might missed something with my derivation. But which part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In going from your line of

$$T\left(n\right)=2\left(2\left(2T\left(n/27\right)+n/9\right)+n/3\right)+n \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

to the generalization of your next line, you forgot that the $2$ factors go across the various terms. As such, each term after the first of your next line should have a factor of $2$ to a decreasing power. For example, the result of expanding \eqref{eq1} becomes

$$T\left(n\right) = 2^3T\left(n/27\right) + 2^2n/9 + 2^1n/3 + 2^0n \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

This, of course, will significantly affect the rest of your calculations.

Comment: Could you explain why we should have a factor of 2 to a decreasing power? 
**T(n/3)=2T(n/3*3)+n/3**  
**T(n)=2T(n/3)+n** when I substitute T(n/3) it shall be **T(n)=2(2T(n/9)+n/3)+n**

Comment: It is basically to do with the factor of $2$ in front of $T$ on the right side. Each substitution will add a factor of $2$. For simplicity, just check your first $2$ equations of $T\left(n\right) = 2T\left(n/3\right) + n$ and $T\left(n/3\right) = 2T\left(n/9\right) + n/3$. Substituting the second one into the first gives $T\left(n\right) = 2\left(2T\left(n/9\right) + n/3\right) + n$, which becomes $T\left(n\right) = 4T\left(n/9\right) + 2n/3 + n$ when you multiply it out. As you can see, there's an extra factor of $2$. If you expand it for $3$ terms, you'll see you get my equation $2$.

Comment: Ah I get it!, it comes when you try to breakdown the parantheses by multiplying 2 for each function(T). I should be more patient tho, thank you very much @John Omielan.

Comment: @Marfin.F Yes, that's it. I'm glad you see it now.